# Is it a good practice to call a method from a model in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, design-patterns, architecture

In the past, when writing my code, I always assumed that the model should just consist of a bunch of auto properties populated by the controller. But I recently came across code like this and want to know if it's valid for MVC:

```
public class SomeModel
{

    public BusinessInfo BusinessInfo { get; set; }
    public IList<BusinessService> BusinessServices { get; set; }
    public IList<BusinessHour> BusinessHours { get; set; }


    public BusinessService GetBusinessServiceByServiceId(int serviceId)
    {
        return BusinessServices.FirstOrDefault(businessService =>
                        businessService.Service.ServiceId == serviceId);
    }
}
```

Is having a method like GetBusinessServiceByServiceId legitimate in this case?

**EDIT:**
This model is used as a strongly typed model for an ASP.NET MVC page, so it essentially acts like a ViewModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say no. If a `ViewModel` requires a `BusinessService` object it should be given it by the `Controller`; finding a `BusinessService` object by its id is the job of a `Repository` class, which a `ViewModel` is not. Also, in the example given, `BusinessServices` should be injected into the `Controller` in its constructor and accessed via in an interface rather than statically; the code example you've got there would be pretty difficult to test.

I personally use `ViewModels` as data holders containing model data and properties indicating if a `View` should display certain elements.

Comment: I generally thought the same thing, but what happens when you need a helper method to be invoked from the view. For example the view contains some IDs and you need to get some data form that id by querying another object in the model? Should that be declared inside the view or as a helper method in some helper class?

Comment: The `ViewModel` should contain everything the `View` needs to display itself, so d'you mean how can the `View` access extra model data which is dependent on (e.g.) a user selecting a particular item? If so, you can use a regular form post back or an AJAX call to a `Controller` method which returns the data the `View` needs. If not, the `ViewModel` should contain other `ViewModels` in its properties so the `View` has everything it needs.

Answer (score 1):

While basicaly having helper methods inside a ViewModel is not forbidden, it sounds like the problem is actually in your View.

One of the goals of the MVC pattern (IMO) was to leave as much of the logic possible inside the controller's Actions.

So again while having helper methods inside a ViewModel is not a bad practice by itself, adding more logic to the View than required is.

**EDIT**: for example, maybe in your example changing the BusinessServices IList inside your ViewModel to a Dictionary would be a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is perfectly valid and common to have methods in your Model classes.

You are probably thinking of other kind of classes. For example, most of the times ViewModels have only properties but no (or very few) methods.

Classes that have only properties and no methods are typically called DTO for "Data Transfer Objects" and Models certainly don't fall on this category.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify, this model acts like a ViewModel for ASP.NET MVC strongly typed view. Does your answer still apply?

Comment: If you are talking about ViewModels then, as I hinted on my answer, the thing is totally different. You should update your question to better reflect your situation.